# Images are not showing after migration and were also not migrated into the files folder

Tags: 8, migrations

I am trying to migrate drupal 7 to drupal 8 using default migration modules ( Migrate, Migrate Drupal, Migrate Drupal UI, Migrate Plus, Migrate Source CSV, Migrate Tools ) using this modules content and text fields and entity refrence fields all are migrated but only image field is not migrated to drupal 8 also drupal 7 existing images are not migrated to drupal 8 /sites/default/files path what am i missing for migrate image field.

Does anyone have any solution?

[image]

Ex : Blank image field showing in migrated article node.

[image]

Comment: You should, if you have followed the recommended process, have a configuration file called migrate_plus.migration.upgrade_d7_file.yml, and this should have a setting for source.constants.source_base_path which points to where the files are located on your D7 site. Have you got this?

Comment: Thanks for replay i will try and implement it in my drupal 7.